# RichTextBox becomes ReadOnly when binding it to content from inside FlowDocumentReader

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

**Question**: In the `btnRevert_Click(...)` event of the following code, how can we make the `RichTextBox` editable?

In my `WPF .NET5` app, the `btnTest_Click(...)` event successfully displays the contents of a `RichTextBox` into a `FlowDocumentReader` (fdReader). Then the `btnRevert_Click(...)` event successfully takes the content back from fdReader and displays it back into `RichTextBox`, but it makes the RichTextBox `ReadOnly`.

I tested the scenario by entering simple text "This is a test" inside RichTextBox, and noted that the above back and forth scenario works fine except that the `btnRevert_Click(...)` event makes the text "This is a test" ReadOnly.

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_RTBFlowDocTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_RTBFlowDocTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Name="mainPanel">
            <ToolBar Name="mainToolBar" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnRevert" Content="Revert" Click="btnRevert_Click"/>
            </ToolBar>
            <RichTextBox Name="rtbTest" AcceptsTab="True"></RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="fdReader" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>Text inside paragraph.</Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentReader>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlowDocument RTBflowDoc = rtbTest.Document;
    rtbTest.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    rtbTest.Document = new FlowDocument();
    fdReader.Document = RTBflowDoc;
    fdReader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void btnRevert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlowDocument fdReaderFlowDoc = fdReader.Document;
    fdReader.Document = new FlowDocument();
    rtbTest.IsReadOnly = false;
    rtbTest.Document = fdReaderFlowDoc;
    rtbTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FlowDocumentReader` provides a control to view a flow content (doesn't support edit).

The following lines in `btnRevert_Click()` method, from question above, just set `rtbTest.Document` to `fdReader.Document`:

```cs
FlowDocument fdReaderFlowDoc = fdReader.Document;
fdReader.Document = new FlowDocument();  
rtbTest.Document = fdReaderFlowDoc;
```

But because of the `FlowDocument` in the `FlowDocumentReader` control doesn't support editing, the easiest way to obtain document from the `FlowDocumentReader` control for editing is to clone it like below:

```cs
private void btnRevert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    var range = new TextRange(fdReader.Document.ContentStart, fdReader.Document.ContentEnd);
    if (!range.IsEmpty)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            range.Save(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
            var copyto = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd, rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd);
            copyto.Load(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        }
    }
    rtbTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    fdReader.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Is there a workaround so that when you get the same content back to RichTextBox it also becomes editable as it was originally?

Comment: @nam: See the updated the `btnRevert_Click()` method above.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you) but it kept the formatting of fdReader. Let me see if I can bring the formatting of RichTexBox back, as well.

Comment: @nam: Of course you will get whole document including formatting! If it's required to get the same document just don't use document from `fdReader`. You have the original document without formatting in the `rtbTest`!

Comment: @nam: BTW in the `btnTest_Click()` method you should clone the `rtbTest.Document` . Don't set  `fdReader.Document` directly to the `rtbTest.Document`. I hope this fix will resolve your problem.

Comment: Your suggestion of  cloning rtbTest.Document instead, worked, as well.

Comment: I have an issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68476757/1232087) in case you get time to comment etc.