# How to horizontally align a CheckBox inside a popup?

Tags: wpf, xaml

**Question**: The following XAML is not hotizontally aligning the `CheckBox` to center. Setting `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` as `StackPanel`'s attribute did not make any difference, either. How can we align it to center?

**NOTE**: I have uploaded a simple test app sample [here](https://ufile.io/r99mmijs) if anyone wants to test it. This link will expire in 30 days from today July 21, 2021.

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
   <Popup Name="MyPopup" Placement="Mouse">
     <StackPanel Background="Bisque">
       <Button Click="Hide_Click" Margin="10">Hide Popup</Button>
       <CheckBox x:Name="chkWebSpeechDefault" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
           <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
          </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
          <TextBlock Text="Set default" FontSize="20"/>
       </CheckBox>
     </StackPanel>
   </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind** [Not specifically relevant to the question]:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

**Display of the above XAML**:

As you can noticed the checkbox is not horizontally aligned to center.

[image: Popup with a check box that is aligned left.]

**UPDATE**
I removed the `TextBlock` and added `Content="Set default"` attribute to `CheckBox`. But it still is aligned to the left. I would like it to be aligned as shown below:

[image: Popup with a check box that is centered.]

Comment: The `CheckBox` control _is_ centered. It's the `TextBlock` you put inside the `CheckBox` that's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a [`RenderTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin?view=net-5.0) in the `Popup` for the `CheckBox` to scale it to half its size.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkWebSpeechDefault" Content="Set default" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
    </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

Render transformations are applied before rendering, but **after the layout phase** (Measure and Arrange). This means that the originally scaled `CheckBox` (which spans almost the full width of the popup) will in fact be aligned horizontally, but it is barely visible. After that, the `CheckBox` will be transformed (only for rendering), but its position and size *in the layout* is still the same as the original, only the scaled rendered image is put in this imaginary bounding box at the top left. That is why it appears not to be centered. You can experiment with this by assigning a large width, e.g. `500`, to the `Popup`, then you will see the centering.

[image: Popup with layout transformation on check box. The check box is not centered properly.]

Now, the solution to the issue is to use a different transformation, a [`LayoutTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform?view=net-5.0).

```
<CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
</CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
```

This transformation is applied **before** the *Measure* and *Arrange* steps, so the layout calculation will consider the real size after scaling and the horizontal alignment is applied to the scaled control.

[image: Popup with layout transformation on check box.]

---

The black line at the bottom using `LayoutTransform` seems to be a rendering artifact.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkWebSpeechDefault" Content="Set default" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True">
```

Enabling layout rounding by setting `UseLayoutRounding` to `true` solves the issue.

[image: No black line at the bottom of the popup through layout rounding.]

There are a few related posts on these kind of issues, `SnapsToDevicePixels` does not work for me.

Comment: And what is the black line on bottom of the `StackPanel`?

Comment: @Jackdaw I have updated the post. This seems to be a rendering issue. These are not pretty, but known in WPF. Usually `SnapsToDevicePixels` or `UseLayoutRounding` can help.

Comment: @thatguy Your suggestion worked. Thank you also for explaining the reasons as to why I was not seeing it centered.